# Multiple if statement in loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I have multiple if statements inside a loop. I am working on fluid flow through pipe and the conditions for my calculation change with which range of numbers the Reynolds number is between.

no-slip Reynolds < 2000 is laminar
no-slip Reynolds > 4000 is turbulent
between is transition

I have all three conditions in their own columns and the if statements should choose one based on the Reynolds number and goes down all of the rows in the sheet.

```vb
For i = 6 To rows + 6 Step 1
    If Range("BQ" & i).Value <=2000 Then
        Range("BV" & i).Value = Range("BR" & i).Value
    End If
    If Range("BQ" & i).Value >= 4000 Then
        Range("BV" & i).Value = Range("BT" & i).Value
    End If
    If 2000 < Range("BQ" & i).Value < 4000 Then
        Range("BV" & i).Value = Range("BU" & i).Value
    End If
Next i
```

RESULT:
[image: Excel sheet]

The Fns column is being filled by Fns Transition even though the Reynolds number is under 2000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bringing this down from my comment:

`2000 < Range("BQ" & i).Value AND Range("BQ" & i).Value < 4000` instead. Otherwise you end up with one half of that inequality range being solved for (`True < 4000`) and then the resulting boolean being compared with 4000, which will always be `True` (I think). Also, instead of separate `if` you should be using `elseif` in here since only one of these conditions should be true at a time.

```
    For i = 6 To rows + 6 Step 1            
        If Range("BQ" & i).Value <=2000 Then
            Range("BV" & i).Value = Range("BR" & i).Value
        ElseIf Range("BQ" & i).Value >= 4000 Then
            Range("BV" & i).Value = Range("BT" & i).Value
        ElseIf 2000 < Range("BQ" & i).Value AND Range("BQ" & i).Value < 4000 Then
            Range("BV" & i).Value = Range("BU" & i).Value
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: That explanation helped a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might have more luck with a Select Case statement:

```
Select Case Range("BQ" & i).Value
    Case Is <= 2000
        Range("BV" & i).Value = Range("BR" & i).Value
    Case Is >= 4000
        Range("BV" & i).Value = Range("BT" & i).Value
    Case Else
        Range("BV" & i).Value = Range("BU" & i).Value
End Select
```

This is easier to read and debug later as well.
Or an Excel formula could do this:

```
=SWITCH(true,BQ2<=2000,BV2,BQ2>=4000,BT2,BU2)
```